# Recycler View in Android not Clicking

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android app. I am facing some problem with opening a popup menu when I click on an Item in the Recycler View.

Show.java (the Activity containing the Recycler View). mRecycler is the object associated with the RecyclerView.

```
mRecycler.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecycler, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(Show.this,mRecycler);
            MenuItem itemView = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.three);
            if(method.equals("Completed"))
                itemView.setTitle("Mark as imcomplete");
            menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup,menu.getMenu());

            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                    int id=item.getItemId();
                    switch (id){
                        case R.id.one:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Show.this,Add.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Task",tasks.get(position));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                            break;
                        case R.id.two:
                            deleteRecord(position);
                            break;
                        case R.id.three:
                            toggleComplete(position);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            onClick(view,position);
        }
    }));
```

Code snippet for xml of RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true" />
```

RecyclerViewClickListener.java

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onClick(View view,int position);
    void onLongClick(View view,int position);
}
```

RecyclerTouchListener.java - class that implements the OnItemTouchListener

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener (Context context,final RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                  final RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener){
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){
                return  true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e){
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener!=null)
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e){
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
        if (child !=null && clickListener !=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
            clickListener.onClick(child,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv,MotionEvent e){}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntecept){}
}
```

Nothing happens when I click an item on the RecyclerView. The android system does not even acknowledge that it was clicked. Please check what is the problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would You please try this

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                menuCardIndex = position;
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Show.this, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(Show.this);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup);
                popupMenu.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            }
        }));

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.one:
            Your_First_Operation;
            return true;
        case R.id.two:
            Your_Second_Operation;
            return true
        case R.id.three:
            Your_Third_Operation;
            return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

finally put this one your activity

```
public class Show extends AppCompactActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener
```

hopefully by this way, You can listen your click listener. if it's working properly, You can set your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If your RecyclerView items have "clickable" children in their XML file, try to declare the property:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Leave the clickable **true** only on the **father** of your list item.

If this is not your case, or you absolutely need clickable elements in your list item, there is another solution.

---

If you are using a RecyclerView, you should have implementend a RecyclerView Adapter somewhere in your code.

In the **OnBindViewHolder** method, try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  //YOUR CODE ...

  holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(yourOnTouchListener);

  //MORE CODE ...
}
```

This will set the OnTouchListener to the single ItemView at the moment the list is generated.

I hope my answer is helpful and understandable enough.